# ASP.NET MVC: Execute code on all Actions (global OnActionExecuting?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a "global" OnActionExecuting that I can override to have *all* my MVC actions (regardless of controller) do something when they get called? If so, how?

Comment: What context would you want to do this in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.  The easiest way to do this is to write a common base class that all of your controller types subclass, then stick an action filter on that base class or override its OnActionExecuting() method.

Comment: Please note that MVC 3 added support for Global Filters

Answer (score 12):

Asp.net MVC3 added support for [Global Filters](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx)

From the ScottGu blog:

ASP.NET MVC supports the ability to declaratively apply “cross-cutting” logic using a mechanism called “filters”.  You can specify filters on Controllers and Action Methods today using an attribute syntax like so:

[image]

Developers often want to apply some filter logic across all controllers within an application.  ASP.NET MVC 3 now enables you to specify that a filter should apply globally to all Controllers within an application.  You can now do this by adding it to the `GlobalFilters` collection.  A `RegisterGlobalFilters()` method is now included in the default Global.asax class template to provide a convenient place to do this (it is then called by the `Application_Start()` method):

[image]

The filter resolution logic in MVC 3 is flexible so that you can configure a global filter that only applies conditionally if certain conditions are met (for example: debugging is enabled, or if a request uses a particular http verb, etc).  Filters can also now be resolved from a Dependency Injection (DI) container.

Answer (score 2):

Create one class that Implements IActionFilter and/or IResultFilter:

```
public class FilterAllActions : IActionFilter, IResultFilter
{      
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And register it on Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //...
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        //...
    }

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new FilterAllActions());
    }
```