# Run on multiple pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to be able to run an action whenever a new page is loaded, so say I got a function in my controller called `checkIfRegistered`

Now, I want that function to run on whatever page the user goes to, how can I do that without copy-pasting like a crazy person?

Thanks

Comment: Using filters, see among others [ASP.NET MVC: Execute code on all Actions (global OnActionExecuting?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430943/asp-net-mvc-execute-code-on-all-actions-global-onactionexecuting)

Comment: Please note that the tag [tag:model-view-controller] is intended for questions about the *pattern*. You've already tagged it with the relevant ASP.NET implementation, so you don't need to (and shouldn't) add the pattern tag.